# How to create int that stores only 2 bits in C++?

Tags: c++, variables

Is there a way how to create variable that can have only one of 3 values?

I want to make a function that returns one of three possible states, I think that use of integer in this case would unnecessarily take lot of space in memory.

So, is there any way how to create variable that stores only 3bits in memory and can be used as a return in function? If so please give me suggestion how to rewrite this into something better:

```
int ReturnOneOfThreeStates(){
     return 0 //Let's say 0=green, 1=red, 2=blue
}
```

Comment: You can see about bitfields.

Comment: The smallest memory you can use is a byte. Even bitset is backed by a byte array. Change your method return type to char.

Comment: If you're storing a whole bunch, I have a way to use only 1.5 bits (well, a little bit more than that) for each value.

Answer (score 13):

> Is there a way how to create variable that can have only one of 3 values?

You can use an enum:

```
enum TriState { One, Two, Three };
```

In C++11, you can specify the underlying integer type with which the enumeration is represented:

```
enum TriState : char { One, Two, Three};
```

A further C++11 nicety is that you can make it *strongly typed*:

```
enum class TriState : char { One, Two, Three};
```

Comment: Note that this will actually be an `int` under the hood (or possibly `unsigned int`)

Comment: I would use an enum and you can even name them more intuitively like enum Color { GREEN, RED, BLUE };

Comment: @KevinBallard I thought the underlying type of a C++03 enum was implementation dependent, rather than specified to be `int`.

Comment: @juan it is implementation-defined for unscoped enums, and `int` for scoped enums (unless made explicit, of course).

Comment: And there's nothing to prevent you from using a cast (or some other trick) to assign a value which doesn't appear.  Many enums, in fact, are used exactly this way.

Comment: enum sounds like really straightforward solution, but if it stores 4 bytes isn't char even better?

Comment: @user1602687 the C++11 examples use `char` as an underlying type, so they are one byte large, just like a single `char`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Technically you're correct. An unscoped enumeration in both C and C++ has an implementation-defined type. In practice, it's probably going to be `int` (or I think `unsigned int` for MSVC++ if the enumeration values are all non-negative). A scoped enumeration in C++11 is specifically `int` unless otherwise specified.

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution would be to create a subrange class,
which stores the value on an `int` (or some other integral
type), and enforces the range invariants in every function which
might modify the value.

Note that the space argument only applies if you have large arrays of the type.  In this case, it's possible to write a `MyValueTypeVector` class, which would only use 2 bits per value (if there are at most three values).  Outside of a large array, the extra code necessary to extract and insert the values would take up more space than the values themselves; in many cases, the compiler will put an `int` in a register, where it wouldn't take up any space at all.  And don't forget that even in a large array, you're probably increasing your access times (from index) by an order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to the answer: you need a way to *return* one of three values, and a way to pack multiple such values in memory.

[Values of *enumerated types*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzy4k6e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) let you solve the first problem: by defining an `enum` you can restrict the declared range of the values returned from a function to just three values. However, this would not let you save any memory: `enum`s cannot be smaller than eight bits.

You need to *pack* smaller values into larger ones to save memory. This works only when you declare arrays of values of sufficient size for the packing to make sense. The basic approach is to cut out the bits that you need, shift them into position, and `OR` in into their desired location.

Here is how you do it with 2-bit numbers: an 8-bit value can store four such numbers. An array of `N` 2-bit values requires `(N+3)/4` 8-bit values. An element at position `x` is in the `x/4` byte, in the position `x%4` (i.e. `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`). You get the desired 2-bit element like this:

```
int twoBit = (array[x/4] >> (2*(x%4))) & 3;
//            ^^^^^^^^^^     ^  ^^^      ^
//                 |         |   |       +-- Get the last two bits
//                 |         |   +---------- Get sub-element 0..3
//                 |         +-------------- Multiply by 2, because there are 2 bits per subelement
//                 +------------------------ Get the desired 8-bit element
```

Setting the value goes the other way around:

```
uint8_t mask = 3 << (2*(x%4));           // Prepare the mask
array[x/4] &= ~mask;                     // Clear out the desired two bits
array[x/4] |= (twoBit & 3) << (2*(x%4)); // OR in the desired bits
```

In cases when you do not need an array, but would like to pack several two-bit values inside a larger `struct` or a `class`, you can use [*Bit Fields*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewwyfdbe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). In this case the compiler will do all the packing to you, if it is possible to pack the data. Note that the order in which you place your data members becomes significant, and can change the amount of memory that you save.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no.
If its part of another class or struct, then yes, you can get the effective benefit using bitfields.

```
// bit_fields1.cpp
struct Date
{
   unsigned nWeekDay  : 3;    // 0..7   (3 bits)
   unsigned nMonthDay : 6;    // 0..31  (6 bits)
   unsigned nMonth    : 5;    // 0..12  (5 bits)
   unsigned nYear     : 8;    // 0..100 (8 bits)
};
```

And you can return a struct with ONLY a single member bitfield (e.g. just one of the fields above) --- but not sure that it will address your case.,  Return values for functions consume at least an 8-bit register on what I imagine are any target machines you care about....

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here.

One is about function arguments and return values and the like that contain just the value you're talking about. There is no way these can take less than a character. And really, having them take less space than an integer isn't terribly useful most of the time.

The other is about storage. Either storage as a member of a class, or some sort of collection of these values. And there you can use various techniques and tricks to have them take less than a byte.

In fact, if you have a large collection of them, or need to store them in a data structure in combination with a number of other types with very restricted value ranges, you can even have them take up fractions of a bit. This will involve a CPU tradeoff to extract the value from the larger data type they share space with. But it is possible.

To some extant, if you are always passing around this small-range value with other values in the same combination, you can turn the function argument question into a storage question. But if they need to be passed directly as arguments, you cannot do this.

I will shortly post a couple of examples of how to define this type for each sort of use.

For value passing, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14571938/167958) has it. Use an `enum`. In C++11 you can choose to say the `enum` will be represented as the smallest possible data type with `enum Foo : char { Val1, Val2, Val3 };`.

For storage of a whole array of them, you can use this technique:

```
#include <limits>

enum Foo : char { Val1, Val2, Val3 };

template <unsigned int NumFoos>
class FooArray {
   static constexpr unsigned int foos_in_x(unsigned long long x) noexcept(true) {
       return (x > 3) ? (1 + foos_in_x(x / 3)) : 0;
   }
   static constexpr unsigned int foos_per_ll = foos_in_x(::std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max());
   static constexpr unsigned long long array_size() noexcept(true) {
       return (NumFoos + (foos_per_ll - 1)) / foos_per_ll;
   }
   static constexpr unsigned int div_value(unsigned int n) {
       return (n == 0) ? 1 : (3 * div_value(n - 1));
   }

 public:
   explicit FooArray(Foo defaultval = Val1);
   ~FooArray();

   Foo operator[](unsigned long long pos) const {
       const unsigned long long arypos = pos / foos_per_ll;
       const unsigned int fooval = (foovals_[arypos] / div_value(pos % foos_per_ll)) % 3;
       return (fooval == 0) ? Val1 : ((fooval == 1) ? Val2 : Val3);
   }

 private:
   unsigned long long foovals_[array_size()];
};
```

Of course, the non-const `operator []` is going to have to return a special reference type that will fiddle with the appropriate value in the array if it's assigned to. If you find how to do that confusing, I could write an example of how the assignment function would work. This is similar to how `::std::bitset` returns the type `reference` from its non-const `operator []`.